# discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was trying to create a Discord bot for me and my friends, and I got this error (title). I don't know how to fix it. I upgraded discord.py and set "intents.messages = True." If I use "intents = discord.Intents.all()," I get an error (that's why I use "intents = discord.Intents.default()"), and I just want to know what I have to do. At this point, this is personal.
Yes I saw another post whit the same error, but that solution didn't work to me
I use python 3.9.12

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import urllib.request
import json
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)
#intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Conectado como {bot.user.name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another intent that works with messages: `intents.message_content = True`

This allows the bot to work with the content of the message not just the message itself.

Comment: Then state what error it is, so that Rexy can edit their answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. However, it's another error, XD. Now it says "discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal," but I put my bot as an admin, and I can't give more permissions.

Comment: Open discord dev portal. Head into "Bot" then scroll down and tick the 3 checkbox under Privileged Gateway Intents

That will help with this error @rodrigoaguilera